# AWS CLI for copying an older version of a file on s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a versioned bucket. I know that I can download older versions, but can I also copy with the aws command line interface (awscli) to s3 itself? Normally this would be something

`aws s3 cp from-loc to-loc`

Comment: The `aws s3` is too simplified / has too much abstraction added for this use case. But you can use the more low level `aws s3api copy-object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [copy-object — AWS CLI Command Reference](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/copy-object.html) you can use:

```
aws s3api copy-object --bucket DESTINATION_BUCKET --key DESTINATION_FILENAME --copy-source 'SOURCE_BUCKET/SOURCE_FILENAME?versionId=VERSION_ID'
```

Note that the `versionId` is specified at the end of the `--copy-source` with: `?versionId=...`

I tried it and it worked correctly:

```bash
$ aws s3api copy-object --bucket my_bucket --key version-output --copy-source 'my_bucket/IMG.jpg?versionId=OXxABkv6CbZ1TFY_oupeHRweEdBJa7_K'
{
    "CopySourceVersionId": "OXxABkv6CbZ1TFY_oupeHRweEdBJa7_K",
    "VersionId": "DJOCWGV79gq01WGVv4BIPIpfBDAPtYLI",
    "ServerSideEncryption": "AES256",
    "CopyObjectResult": {
        "ETag": "\"cf0accb1b590bc16f3806b270a03132d\"",
        "LastModified": "2023-06-06T08:13:50+00:00"
    }
}
```

Comment: If we use `--version` doesn't work as it just prints the aws cli version.

Comment: My example does not use `--version`.  Please note that the `versionId` is specified at the end of the `--copy-source`.

Comment: Yes because I tried with `--version` and it didn't work so just added the info here :)